# Angular JS: retrieve json data based on id

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of items. When you click on an item it recognizes its id and takes you to its corresponding page localhost:8000/products/1.

But how do I get the rest of the information just for that one product/item id?

My json data looks like this...

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Chips",
    "subTitle": "Snack",
    "imgUrl": "chips.png",
    "demoImgUrl": "snacks.png",
    "brandLogoUrl": "somebrand.png"
  },
...
```

my **productList.js** where it **successfully** shows the list of products

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('testProducts')
    .component('productList', {
      templateUrl: '/components/productList/productList.html',
      controller: ProductListController
    });

  ProductListController.$inject = ['ProductsService'];

  function ProductsListController(ProductsService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.products = [];

    // Get the Products data
    ProductService.getData().then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
      vm.products = response.data;
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.error('Error', err);
    });
  }

})();
```

and my **item.js** where it should grab the json for that one id

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('testProducts')
    .controller('itemController', ItemController);

  ItemController.$inject = ['$state', '$stateParams', 'ProductsService'];

  function ItemController($state, $stateParams, ProductsService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.itemId = $stateParams.itemId;
    console.log($stateParams.itemId);

    // Get the Product data
    ProductsService.getData().then(function(response) {
       console.log(response.data);
    }).catch(function(err) {
       console.error('Error', err);
    });
  }

})();
```

And my html **item.html** (which does not render title or imgUrl)

```
<div>
  <p>itemId: {{$ctrl.itemId}}</p>
  <p>{{$strl.title}}</p>
  <img src="{{$ctrl.imgUrl}}" />
</div>
```

I've gotten

> angular.js:13236 ReferenceError: ProductService is not defined

So how do I just display the information based on the json data item id?

Comment: You inject ProductsService not ProductService, you hava a typo.

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi Good catch! thank you :) However I still don't know how to grab that specific id json data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$filter` to retrieve desired object based using any property. Its syntax is `$filter('filter')(vm.products, { Id: 1 })`. `vm.products` is the data nothing but list of objects and it will return list of all objects which has Id 1.

Comment: Got filter to work. However I still don't know how to throw it into my template. :\